# How do you specify VPC with Ansible ec2_lc module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm trying to use Ansible to create a launch configuration.  I'm using the ec2_lc module as detailed at http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_lc_module.html.

I'm creating the launch configuration and specifying some security groups that are not part of my default VPC.  However, it will not let me do this.  It appears to be defaulting to the default VPC, and I don't see a setting in the docs to change this.  Is there something I'm overlooking?  The output from my playbook is as follows:

```
TASK: [aws-lc | building new aws launch configuration] ************************ 
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true}
msg: BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://autoscaling.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-01-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>ValidationError</Code>
    <Message>The security group 'xyz-general-sg' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-3Cef6a45'</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>54121d19-1f30-11e5-1121-51263ee1684e</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using VPCs you must specify the security group id instead of security group names that are only accepted in EC2 Classic. [1]

If you are not using names check if you didn't misspelled the security group id.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-launch-configuration.html